# Javascript Back Button Behavior

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have a site I'm building where one of my pages contains several tab-panes. Whenever the user clicks on one of these tab-panes it updates the browser's history and thus affects the browser's back button functionality in an undesirable way. I've searched around on this site, but everything I found was people wanting the browser to take the user back to the previous tab, which isn't what I want. I want the browser to take the user back to the previous page, not the previous tab on the same page, if that makes sense.

I assume there should be a simple way to do this, but I just can't find it. Seems like I'm kind of alone in this want of mine.

The site is built with aspx and visual studios mvc framework.

here is a small code sample.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
     <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab3">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
     <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
     </div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
     </div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That really is hard to follow, but I think you should consider making a link that causes this behaviour instead of trying to manipulate the browser's built-in functionality.

Comment: Well we have no idea what tabs code you are using and how it is implemented. Basically impossible to give you an answer.

Comment: @epascarello I added a small code sample. Sorry I didn't include that in the original post. I didn't think it would be of much value to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a know issue

you will need to use the javsacript method  `window.location.replace(url);`

using window.location.replace() the current page will not be saved in session history

Comment: This seems like a good solution, though catching the back button click event might be tricky. Would it be possible to just stop the navigation Tabs from updating the URL in the first place?